# Show $\int_{\partial G} f =0$ when $f$ is only continuous on boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a simply connected open set.

Let $f$ be analytic in $G$, and continuous in $\bar{G}$.

Let $\gamma = \partial G$. I want to prove that $\int_\gamma f dz =0$. 
Note that $\gamma$ is not contained in $G$.

My attempt: (found to be wrong)
Thanks.

Comment: Add your attempt anyway, maybe it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : Try to build a sequence of paths $\gamma_n$ which are included in $G$ and such that $$\int_{\gamma_n} fdz \to \int_{\gamma} fdz,$$ when $n \to \infty.$ Since $\int_{\gamma_n} fdz = 0$ because $f$ is analytic on $G$, you will get the conclusion.

**Edit** : First try to show it for a the standard disk $D(0,1)$. If $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$, then $\gamma_n(t) = \left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right) \gamma(t)$ will work. (It's not completely trivial but this is standard analysis.) For the general case, I assume you know about Riemann-Koebe theorem which will allow you to work with $D(0,1)$ instead if $G$.

Comment: I am not sure whether this works... especially the domain of integration is different. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I think that some regularity on $\gamma$ will be required.

Comment: Without any regularity assumption on $\partial G$, this idea is very difficult to work out.

Answer (score 3):

This is very tricky to do in full generality if we don't assume some boundary regularity of the domain, and wasn't proved until the 1930's.

The following is due to Denjoy (1933)

> **Theorem** If $\gamma$ is a rectifiable Jordan curve and $f$ is holomorphic on the interior $G$ of $\gamma$ and continuous on $\bar G = G \cup \gamma$, then
>   $$ \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0. $$

Using [Mergelyan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem) (from 1951) we can give a very short proof: Approximate $f$ uniformly on $\bar G$ by a sequence of polynomials $p_n$. Then $\int_{\partial G} p_n(z)\,dz = 0$ (using only the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus). Take the limit as $n\to\infty$.