# True or False? If $f(z)$ is analytic in a simply connected domain $D$ and continuous in $\bar{D}$, then $\oint_{\delta D}f(z)dz=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is analytic in a simply connected domain D and continuous in $\bar{D}$, then $\oint_{\partial D}f(z)dz=0$.

I think we can say this is true but I am having a hard time forming a proof other than since it is continuous on the boundary, we can't have any new singularities from the analytic domain to the boundary.

Comment: I don't think it's true. I'm thinking the function $e^{x-1/x}$ with $D$ be the disk of radius 1 about 1 might be a counter example

Comment: Oh interesting.. Because then $e^{x-1/x}$ would have division by 0 at the point (0,0)...

Comment: I wonder though if that division by 0 breaks the continuity requirement

Comment: The two situations seem very different.  In the second case, we have that $f$ is analytic in $D_1$ and $D_2$ and continuous on the boundary curve that's common to the two regions, so it can be continued analytically from one region to the other.  In the first case, we don't know anything about analytic continuation.  It may not be possible to continue the function past *any* point on the boundary.  I'm not sure, but I think the answer to the original question is "no".

Comment: Are you assuming $\partial D$ is a nice enough curve to integrate over?  It might be non-rectifiable, in which case it's not so clear what $\oint_{\partial D} f(z)\; dz$ means.

Comment: You may be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is "yes" subject to some geometric details.  There is an explanation at 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem.  Here's the relevant paragraph.

[image: Here's the relevant paragraph]

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Kodaira reference.